# Evaluate int Variable value in Decimal in expression

Tags: ssis

I have a scenario in SSIS where I am using @BadRecordCount in rowcount transformation to count bad records and @TotalRecordCount in rowcount transformation to count total records. I need to calculate ErrorPercentage. To do this I declared another variable @ErrorPercentage and used expression - **@[User::RowCountBad] *100 / @[User::TotalRecordsCount]**.

The expression is evaluating fine but doesn't give decimal value.

I tried changing my variable datatype to **double** but it is still evaluating it as integer.

I tried changing variable value to string the it throwing an error saying "*" is not allowed in specified datatype which means I cant multiply in expression.

Finally, I tried changing @BadRecordCount and @TotalRecordCount variables datatype to double along with @ErrorPercentage. Now, it is evaluating with decimal which is what I want, but when I run the package, it fails saying change @BadRecordCount and TotalRecordCount to INT as those are being used by rowcount transformation.

I want for example:

@[User::RowCountBad] =10000 and @[User::TotalRecordsCount] = 143000 then as the calculation it is giving me 6.993006993006993.

as per the expression above it is giving me only 6 but I need 6.99(up to 2 decimal).

Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: Where are you calculating ErrorPercentage? Is this in a Derived Column of a data flow task? Is it an Expression on a Variable? Is this .NET code?

Answer (score 0):

SSIS Expressions are so painful - no implicit conversions.

I would try something like this:

(DT_NUMERIC,10,2)@[User::RowCountBad] * (DT_NUMERIC,10,2)100 / (DT_NUMERIC,10,2)@[User::TotalRecordsCount]